# Fourier analysis expansion $f(x) = \sin(x)$

Tags: fourier-series

I am reading a book on Fourier analysis and I am having difficulty in understanding a step in the expansion of the function  $f(x) = \sin(x), 0 \lt x \lt \pi$ as a Cosine Fourier series. I attached the problem with the step highlighted in a red box, anyone able to explain how this result was reached?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $b_n = 0$ means the sine coefficients must be 0, and that is because the function is even ( all sines are odd ). The rest is just applying the addition formula for sines and integrate. The red box is using $\cos(v+\pi) = -\cos(v)$ which you will realize if you take a look on the unit circle. Both x and y switch sign if you perform a half revolution.